# Delete action doesn't work with related models in Yii

Tags: php, yii, relationship

I have these relations in two models (photo, album). In item model:

```
'photo' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'photo', 'album_id')
```

In photo model:

```
'album' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Album', 'album_id'),
```

And in actionDelete of albumController:

```
 $this->loadModel($id)->photo->delete();
```

But nothing happens and the album doesn't get deleted.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Album has many photos in your relation, you should delete them in a loop

```
$photos = $this->loadModel($id)->photo;
foreach($photos as $photo)
    $photo->delete();
```

Or you may delete them in one query:

```
Photo::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array('album_id'=>$id))
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you have `HAS_MANY` relation, you'll have to delete many objects, so to make it happen using 1 call, you can do it through the other model, so in the `Album` model put this method:

```
public function deletePhotos() {    
    return Photo:::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array('album_id' =>$this->id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is usunig data base [Relational model](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/Database-Relationships-An-Introduction-To-Foreign-Keys-Joins-And-E-R-Diagrams.htm) first of all it work's faster, second you don't need to write a lot of php code